# How should I create a single score with two values as input?

Tags: statistics

I have two series of values, a and b as inputs and I want to create a score, c, which reflects both of them equally.  The distribution of a and b are below

[image: Distribution of a]
[image: Distribution of b]

In both cases, the x-axis is just an index.

How should I go about creating an equation c = f(a,b) such that a and b are (on average) represented equally in c?

Edit: c = (a+b)/2 or c = ab will not work because c will be too heavily weighted by a or b.

I need a function, f, where c = f(a,b) and c' = f(a + stdev(a),b) = f(a, b + stdev(b))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're looking for something where A and B are equally represented, consider trying something like Z score normalization (or [standard score](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_score)):

```
c = (a-u_a)/sigma_a + (b-u_b)/sigma_b
```

That score equally represents the two, but would be on a smaller scale.  It really shouldn't matter since the numbers are arbitrary, however, if you need to scale it up, you could do something like:

```
c2 = (sigma_a+sigma_b)*(c) + u_a + u_b
```

Answer (score 1):

using R syntax:

```
 c <- a/2+b/2
```

or you can create a function:

```
c <- function(a,b) { return(a/2+b/2) }
```

Comment: That's not going to help me. If I use an arithmetic mean, the score will be too heavily weighted by b in most cases. I need a change in each to equally be capable of influencing c.